# Whats wrong with this priority queue logic java?

Tags: java

I keep getting a null pointer exception when adding to this queue, especially with the percolate up. I think something is wrong with my set up but I can't figure it out. When I try to add things I get an error and my IDE says its a null pointer exception and a problem in the compare methods, making me think that the if else statements in the compare method point to a null value. I can't figure out why they would?

```
public class GenericHeap<E> {
int size;
int capacity = 10;
public E[] heap;
Comparator mycomparator;

public GenericHeap(Comparator c) {
    heap = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    mycomparator = c;

}
public void add(E e) {
    if (size == 0) {
        heap[size++] = e;
    } else {
        heap[size++] = e;
        this.percolateup(this.size);

    }

}

private void percolateup(int I) {
    E temp;
    while (I / 2 > 0) {
        if (mycomparator.compare(heap[I / 2], heap[I]) == 1) {
            temp = heap[I / 2];

            heap[I / 2] = heap[I];
            heap[I] = temp;

        }
        I = I / 2;

    }
}
 public int compare(String t, String t1) {
    if (t.length()>t1.length()){
    return 1;}
    else if (t.length()<t1.length()){
    return -1;}
    return t.compareTo(t1);


}}
```

Comment: Well, have you stepped through your code in the debugger? That is step #1.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Seems like you are adding an object, which has not been instantiated, to your Queue. Make sure that the object you are adding to the Queue is instantiated and has a valid reference. Also, you haven't given the full code here. Where is the Queue?

Comment: What type is `heap`? When you do `heap[size++]`, how can you be sure that the object you are trying to access (element of `heap`) actually exists?

Comment: I edited and added the constructor and instance variables. I realized I need to add an increase capacity method, but I was getting errors when my tester wasn't exceeding the capacity.

Comment: Can you also post the test driver you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your index one step ahead, to where the heap[I] is still null.

Say you are adding your 2nd item.

@entry: size==1

you go down the else path, setting `heap[1]=e`, THEN incrementing size to 2.  You then call `percolateup(2)`.  Notice what happens when I==2 here:

```
if (mycomparator.compare(heap[I / 2], heap[I]) == 1) {
```

you access `heap[2]`, which of course has not yet been set.  NPE !

Above is definitely why you are getting the NPE...now to speculate further. I don't really understand the logic of percolateup(), but I bet the issue is you are advancing the value of size too aggressively.  Possibly instead of:

```
heap[size++] = e;
this.percolateup(this.size);
```

this might help

```
heap[size] = e;
this.percolateup(this.size);
size++
```

Separately, you have a style which lends to this confusion.  In `add()` you reference member variable `size` directly (`size++`).  Nothing wrong with that; but then you turn around and access `this.size`.  Compiler is happy but this inconsistent style is not helping your comprehension. (I personally prefer to only use "this." when absolutely required, but that's personal taste.)